# Why WebRTC only support H264 in Chrome but not in native application with some devices

Tags: android, webrtc, h.264

I use [official sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/create-offer/) to create offer SDP in Android Chrome, we can find `a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000` that meant it can support H264.

But if I build [AppRTC(official Android sample)](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/androidapp) and use  [official prebuilt libraries](https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc) version 1.0.25821, call createOffer then receive SDP in `SdpObserver::onCreateSuccess`, the SDP did **not** contain H264.

My test device is Oppo R15 (with MTK Helio P60, Android 8.1).

So, why WebRTC only support H264 in Chrome but not in native application with some Android devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome build uses **openh264 which is not used by regular **WebRTC**. What I meant by regular is that there is variant with software **h.264** encoder from the chrome build which you may use but I wouldn't recommend it.

On Android **WebRTC**, H.264 is supported only if

1. device hardware supports it, AND
2. WebRTC hardware encoder glue logic supports that hardware encoder. Currently only **QCOM** and **EXYNOS** devices are supported. So any other devices even if they support h.264 HW encoder,  won't be used and won't be added as part of codec factory and you won't see in SDP generated from WebRTC sample apps.

At Java level, you can see that in `HardwareVideoEncoderFactory.java` which checks for QCOM and EXYNOS devices in `isHardwareSupportedInCurrentSdkH264` function.

Interestingly, if you are using native code, even QCOM and EXYNOS hardware encoders are not supported (there is bug filed on Webrtc issue tracker). This is because of tight integration of HW encoding  code with JNI code - definitely not a good modular code.

Comment: I found [this commit](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/28e710798eaaf5d7d17ee9464dacdae258248d5d) said "Only allow MediaTek H264 HW Codec for O_MR1 or later". What is `MediaCodecVideoEncoder.java` used for?

Comment: Looked at that commit - it's still under field trial. You can enable it in official sample app by passing field trial key **"WebRTC-MediaTekH264/Enabled/"**

Comment: I got it. First, `setFieldTrials` with **"WebRTC-MediaTekH264/Enabled/"**, use `MediaCodecVideoEncoder::isH264HwSupported` to check. Then, instead of `DefaultVideoEncoder/DecoderFactory` to  `MediaCodecVideoEncoder/Decoder::createFactory`. But we should to know `MediaCodecVideoEncoder` is deprecated.